# Google Sheets delete row based on table values

Tags: google-sheets

I have Google form feeding into a sheet.
When a row is updated there is a Name column and ID column.
If the ID column does not match the Name column for the specific row based on the table on a separate sheet, I am looking for this to automatically delete the row in the feed sheet (Sheet1). Attached is the idea.
I hope this makes sense! Thanks in advance.

[image: Google Sheet]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. P.S. start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Answer (score -1):

So if the name matches but the ID is different, delete ?

Then something like this will work I think.

```
  for(j = 1; j < sheet2.length; j++) {
    if((form(name) == sheet2(j)(name) && form(ID) == sheet2(j)(ID)) {
      post the entry
    }
  }
```